# How to execute class on generic type in java

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-11

I have an example generic method. How to execute class keyword on generic type **T** like below?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class BaseTag {
    public <T> T getW() {
        String[] arr = {"A", "B", "C"};
        return Arrays.stream(arr)
                // .filter(arg -> T.class.isAssignableFrom(arg.getClass()))     // another example
                .map(T.class::cast)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't due to type erasure etc. However, you can do something like `getW(Class<T> type)` and then use `type` for the cast.

Comment: If you method always returns a `String`, it is not generic.